# Starting a shell script which calls programs with GUI via cronjob after system startup don't work

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, raspberry-pi

I wrote myself a script combination which displays two different webcams with ffplay and arranges the windows accordingly via xdotool. - This script also works when I start it manually.

But when I enter this script in the crontab @reboot the windows are not displayed. The webcams light up and when I try to start the script manually it tells me that it does not work because the camera is already in use.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the GUI to display accordingly after system startup?

Attached are the scripts. Please ignore the naming and senseless division of the individual points.

**Script for webcam 1 (video0):**

```
#!/bin/bash

ffplay /dev/video0 -x 640 -y 512
```

**Script for webcam 2 (video2):**

```
#!/bin/bash

ffplay /dev/video2 -x 640 -y 512
```

**Script for positioning the windows**

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5s

xdotool search --name /dev/video0 windowmove 0 0

sleep 0.4

xdotool search --name /dev/video2 windowmove 640 0

exit 0
```

The three scripts are located under Documents/Scripts/

And the script that calls the three scripts. This is located under Desktop/

```
#!/bin/bash

bash /home/pi/Documents/Skripte/webcam1.sh &

bash /home/pi/Documents/Skripte/webcam2.sh &

bash /home/pi/Documents/Skripte/startup.sh
```

**And finally the Crontab entry**

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/pi/Desktop/startup.sh
```

Comment: You can try `/home/pi/Desktop/startup.sh > /tmp/start.log 2>&1` and you should see in `/tmp/start.log` messages like : DISPLAY is not setup properly.

Comment: The dupe aspect aside, why cron? If you automatically log into the Gooey, why don't you just use your Window Managers autostart feature?

Comment: I found a solution: [auto start unter raspbian](https://christian-brauweiler.de/autostart-unter-raspbian/)